# Swift DateTimeFormatter TimeZone

Tags: ios, swift, datetime, dateformatter

I'm trying to convert a date-time string to a date, with a `DateFormatter` with the `TimeZone` set to UTC.

The input string is in the format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'`.

For some reason, the subsequent `Date` produced is in UTC - 1:00:00. For example a date-time string of `"2023-04-28T12:18:15Z"` is producing a `Date` of `2023-04-28 11:18:15 UTC`.

```
    let inputLogDateFormatter: DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    private init() {
        self.inputLogDateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
        self.inputDateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
        self.inputDateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    }
......
let logDateTime: String = // LogString in 'inputLogDate' format.
let date: Date = self.inputLogDateFormatter.date(from: logDateTime) ?? Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 0) // Produces a time - 1 hour from input time string.
```

Comment: Check your init, you are configuring some other date formatter object in the last two lines.

Comment: The `Z` in the string represents the timezone. Don't ignore it. Do not quote the `Z` in the format and then there is no need to set a timezone on the formatter.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes, you're completely right. Definitely a facepalm moment! Thank you!

Comment: What is the reason not to use [ISO8601DateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/iso8601dateformatter)?

Comment: @vadian The input string isn't in the format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS`?

Comment: Your sample string matches the requirements of `ISO8601DateFormatter`, even fractional seconds can be parsed.